# Regarding updating list

Tags: python, python-2.7

im trying to update a 2 dimensional list i use for keeping track of a stage in a console game. I use the following code for updating:

```
def updateBoard():
    stage[bird[0]][3] = "#"
    #print(bird) Debugging
    #print(stage) Debugging
```

and this snippet for flushing the board on a new update:

```
def flushBoard():
    stage = 0
    stage = [[0 for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]
    #print(stage) Debugging
```

The snippet used for printing the board is the following:

```
def printBoard():

    for row in stage:
        for square in row:
            print(square, end="")
        print("")
    print("")
    print(stage)
```

The problem i get is, after flushing then updating, i get the "bird" on the new spot, but i get it on the previous spot also, even after flushing the list. Any reasons why? NOTE: The stage is a global variable declared on top of the file, while the functions are run in the proper order in a while loop. (Flush, Update, Print) NOTE: im using **future** to get the proper print function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in flushBoard you are using local stage instead of global. That's what happens when you use assignment. You should do:

```
def flushBoard():
    global stage
    stage = 0
    stage = [[0 for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]
    #print(stage) Debugging
```

I'd recommend to read **[Python docs on variable scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)**.

Comment: Those are not the python docs my friend, these are: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html

Answer (score 0):

If `stage` is a global variable, you have to use the `global` keyword. Right now, you are just declaring and creating a new `stage` within the scope of the `flushBoard` function.

```
def flushBoard():
    global stage  # use globally defined stage in this function
    stage = [[0 for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]
```

In the other methods, where you just access or modify `stage`, `global` is not needed.

Having said that, you could also use the `[:]` slice notation to *modify* the list, replacing it's entire content with new values. This way, you do not need `global`.

```
def flushBoard():
    stage[:] = [[0 for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]
```